# Batch file To check if the files are present in a folder comparing the names from a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a batch file which checks if the file names present in a text file are present in a folder. 
I have a folder called PAN where i have a text file named as PRAS_filelist.txt which stores all the file names. And a folder PRAS in which all my files are present.

My requirement is it should scan the folder and at the end, it should populate a error message in a file PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG. but now it is coming out if any one file is not present since i have used exit.

Below is the code

```
`rm -f ../SessLogs/PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG`
for i in `cat ./PAN/PRAS_filelist.txt`
do
    file_name=$i
    if [ -e ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_* ]
    then
        if [ -s ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_* ]
        then
            a=`sed -n '1p' ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_*|cut -d'|' -f1`
            b=`sed -n '$p' ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_*|cut -d'|' -f1`
            if [ "$a" == "H" ] && [ "$b" == "T" ]
            then
                trailer_record=`sed -n '$p' ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_*|cut -d'|' -f2`
                record_count=`wc -l ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_*|cut -d' ' -f1`
                r_c=`expr $record_count - 1`
                if [ $trailer_record -eq $r_c ]
                then
                    `cp ./PAN/PRAS/"$file_name"_* ./PAN/PRAS/STANDARDIZE/"$file_name"`
                    `sed -i '$d' ./PAN/PRAS/STANDARDIZE/"$file_name"`
                else 
                    echo "ERROR in file $file_name: Count of records is $r_c and trailer is $trailer_record">../SessLogs/PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG  
                fi  
            else
                echo "ERROR in file $file_name: header or trailer is missing">../SessLogs/PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG
                exit 1 
            fi 
        else
            echo "ERROR in file $file_name: empty file">../SessLogs/PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "ERROR: $file_name doesnot exist">../SessLogs/PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: Linux has shell scripts, not batch files or cmd.exe - and that's not a cmd script.  Poorly chosen tags by the look of it.

Comment: *...but now it is coming out if any one file is not present since i have used exit.* Don't use `exit`.

Comment: You shouldn't use back-ticks for stand-alone commands on the command line. You have a few cases where you do that, such as the first `rm...`, the `cp...` command and your `sed -i...`. In those cases, the command will run, then the shell will attempt to execute whatever they output to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refactoring your code a bit:

One odd thing is that you claim to have a list of filenames, but then you append an underscore before you check the file exists. Do the actual filenames actually have underscores?

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

logfile=../SessLogs/PRAS_PP_ERROR_LOG
rm -f $logfile

while read file_name; do
    files=( ./PAN/PRAS/${file_name}_* )
    if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
        echo "ERROR: no files named ${file_name}_*"
        continue
    elif (( ${#files[@]} > 1 )); then
        echo "ERROR: multiple files named ${file_name}_*"
        continue
    fi

    f=${files[0]}

    if [[ ! -s $f ]]; then
        echo "ERROR in file $f: empty file"
        continue
    fi

    a=$(sed    '1q' "$f" | cut -d'|' -f1)
    b=$(sed -n '$p' "$f" | cut -d'|' -f1)

    if [[ "$a" != "H" || "$b" != "T" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR in file $f: header or trailer is missing"
        continue
    fi 

    trailer_record=$(sed -n '$p' "$f" | cut -d'|' -f2)
    r_c=$(( $(wc -l < "$f") - 1 ))

    if (( trailer_record == r_c )); then
        sed '$d' "$f" > ./PAN/PRAS/STANDARDIZE/"$file_name"
    else 
        echo "ERROR in file $f: Count of records is $r_c and trailer is $trailer_record"
    fi  

done < ./PAN/PRAS_filelist.txt | tee $logfile
```